# build a string that can serve as a boolean

Tags: r

I want to build this string (boolean?), `A_bool`, from the components listed below. `df` is a dataframe with attributes `Class`, `V1`, and `V2` and if `A_bool` is run like this `A=df[A_bool,]`, then `A` should be a data frame with an "appropriately" extracted set of rows.

```
A_bool=df$Class=='democrat'& df$V1=='y' & df$V2=='n'

dfv=c("df$","df$","df$")
vars=c("Class","V1","V2")
ops=c("==", "==", "==")
vals=c('democrat','y','n')
A_bool=paste(dfv,vars,ops,vals,sep="") #doesn't work.
```

My attempt did not work because it is a character vector and does not have the correct quotes.

Comment: The answer involves `parse`. However, as [Fortune](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fortunes/vignettes/fortunes.pdf) 106 tells us, "If the answer is parse() you should usually rethink the question". Why are you doing this?

Comment: I want to build a function, say, myEvent, which will accept dfv, vars, ops, vals and generate a generalized df[A_bool,].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`paste` returns a character, which you'd need to parse. However, parsing is strongly discouraged because it is inefficient, results in code being less readable and can create serious security problems.

Here is an example of a better approach using a `for` loop. Note how I use `[[` instead of `$` (see `help("Extract")`). I also utilize that logical operators are functions in R.

```
myEvent <- function(DF, vars, ops, vals) {
  ops <- lapply(ops, getFunction)
  idx <- TRUE
  for (i in seq_along(ops)) {
    idx <- idx & ops[[i]](DF[[vars[[i]]]], vals[[i]])
  }
  DF[idx,]
}

myEvent(iris, c("Sepal.Length", "Species"), 
        c("<", "=="), list(5, "setosa"))
```

Comment: Thank you. That looks pretty complicated. Isn't there something more simple and closer to what I was trying?

Comment: can you tell me what getFunction is? I cannot find examples or simple info on it when I google "getFunction" r

Comment: See `help("getFunction")`. It does exactly what its name suggests. It looks in the search path for a function specified by a character string and returns that function if it is found. In practice, it is very similar to `get`, but only returns functions.